# Cannot set an NSWindow's position

Tags: objective-c, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I have a class that extends NSWindowController and I am trying to position the window it controls. The window displays all of the expected contents and functions correctly, but when I try and position its starting location on the screen in the initWithWindowNibName method, the position does not change. Here is the code:

```
NSPoint p = NSMakePoint(100, 50);
[[self window] setFrameTopLeftPoint:p];
```

This seems very straight forward and I'm not sure what the problem is.

Thanks for any ideas.

(Found the problem. I did not have the window wired up to the Class in IB.)

Comment: A declaration and one line of code is not enough. If I copy and paste that code into my program, it will work, meaning I can't reproduce your bug.

Answer (score 3):

Wevah has the right idea, though I'll try to expand on it a bit.

If you were to try adding this line to your `initWithWindowNibName:` method:

```
NSLog(@"window == %@", [self window]);
```

You would likely see the following output to console:

```
window == (null)
```

In other words, the window is still `nil`, as `init*` methods are so early on in an object's lifetime that many `IBOutlet`s or user interface items aren't quite "hooked up" yet.

Sending a message to `nil` is perfectly fine: it's simply ignored. So, basically your attempt to position the window has no effect because it basically equates to `[nil doSomething]`;

The key then is to perform the positioning of the window later on in the controller object's lifetime, where the `IBOutlet`s and other user interface objects are properly hooked up. As Wevah alluded to, one such method where things are properly hooked up is

```
- (void)awakeFromNib;
```

or in the case of `NSWindowController`, the following one as well:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad;
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Try putting that code in `awakeFromNib`.